# Rsync cannot sync a large list of files

Tags: centos, backup, rsync

I have a script that uses rsync to backup of my files from my server to my local machine.

The problem is that, when I need to do a sync of a large list of files, the rsync can't sync. It starts to count the files, and when the files counter was finished, it starts to count again. After that, it launch the erros below:

```
2016/10/24 17:27:15 [97451] rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (52776589 bytes received so far) [receiver]
2016/10/24 17:27:15 [97451] rsync error: error in rsync protocol data stream (code 12) at /SourceCache/rsync/rsync-35.2/rsync/io.c(452) [receiver=2.6.9]
2016/10/24 17:27:15 [97422] rsync: connection unexpectedly closed (52776589 bytes received so far) [generator]
2016/10/24 17:27:15 [97422] rsync error: unexplained error (code 255) at /SourceCache/rsync/rsync-35.2/rsync/io.c(452) [generator=2.6.9]
```

The size of files list is aproximately 2mi files.
The rsync version on the server is 3.0.6 and on my local machine is 3.1.

The command line that I'm using is:

```
synchronize() {
  echo $USER | $RSYNC -azvP --delete  --timeout=6000 --rsync-path="sudo ionice -c3 nice -n19 ${RSYNC} --bwlimit=10000" \
     --log-file=$LOGFILE admin@XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:"${1}"  "${DESTINATION}${2}"
}
```

The Rsync is configured to not ask for a password on the server side.

Anybody knows why this errors happened?

Thanks

Comment: Have you monitored the target system during the `rsync` execution? anything abnormal (e.g file descriptors exhaustion, etc ...)?

Comment: Yes, everything looks normal, the CPU is 99% idel, but I don't know how to check the current usage of files descriptors, can you explain?

Comment: You seem to be login in the remote system as `admin`, if you `ssh` into the remote system as `admin` and check the `ulimit -a` settings, you'll be able to see all the limits configured for this user. Since you are trying to sync a lot of files, you might be hitting the any of these limits. Just a theory, though. `lsof` can help monitoring the number of file descriptors.

Comment: Have you tried to run a similar script with ten files (i.e. a smaller set) and confirmed the issue disappears?

Comment: Hi folks, `unlimit -a` returns `open files 1024`, when I run the script for a smaller number of files, the problem does not happened. Is there a way to increase the number of open files only during rsync session?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after some help of @dawud found that the problem is the number of open files exceed the SO limit, so to avoid change the SO configuration, I have decided change my script to sync individual directories (the result will be the same).

So my new script is:

```
synchronize() {
  echo admin@XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:"${1}"  "${DESTINATION}${2}"
  echo $USER | $RSYNC -azvP --delete --rsync-path="sudo ionice -c3 nice -n19 rsync --bwlimit=10000" \
     --log-file=$LOGFILE admin@XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX:"${1}"  "${DESTINATION}${2}" 2>&1 1> /dev/null
}

synchronize_list() {
  directories_list=($(ssh admin@XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX ls "${1}"))
  for i in "${directories_list[@]}"; do
    echo "SYNC DIRECTORY:  ${i}"
    synchronize "${1}/${i}" "${i}"
  done
}

synchronize_list "/home" "home/"
```

I hope this chunk of code help you guys.

Thanks.